# Foreign key Relation : UniDirectional annotation hibernate

Tags: java, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-one, hibernate-annotations

I need to save two entities at once in mysql table . The below are two entities
one is UserEntity and other one is UserDetailsEntity. I want to insert UserId column in UserDetails table as foreign key. but UserId is not getting inserted in UserDetails Table. Help me in this Plz.

> UserEntity.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "UserId")
private int id;

@Column(name = "UserLogin", length = 15, unique = true)
private long phNumber;

@Column(name = "Password", length = 100)
private String password;

@Column(name = "UserType", length = 20)
private String userType;

@Column(name = "PromoCode", length = 20)
private String promoCode;

@Column(name = "FirstName", length = 30)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "LastName", length = 30)
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "RoleId")
private int roleId;

@Column(name = "isActive")
private int isActive;

@Column(name = "isTestUser")
private int isTestUser;

@Column(name = "FcmToken", length = 100)
private String fcmToken;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserId", unique = true,insertable = true, updatable = true) 
//@ForeignKey(name = "UserId")
private UserDetailsEntity userDetailsEntity;
```

// getters and setters

> UserDetailsEntity.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "UserDetailsId")
private int id;


@Column(name="UserId", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters={@Parameter(name="property", value="uid")})    
private int userId;

@Column(name ="AadhaarCardNumber" ,length = 12)
private long aadhaarNumber;

@Column(name="", length = 50)
private String emailId; 

@Column(name="Address1" , length = 30)
private String address1;

@Column(name="Address2", length = 30)
private String address2;

@Column(name="CityId", length = 10)
private int cityId;

@Column(name="StateId", length = 10)
private int stateId;

@Column(name="CountryId", length = 10)
private int countryId;

@Column(name="Latitude", length = 60)
private String lat;

@Column(name="Longitude", length = 60)
private String lng;

@Column(name="MobileNumber1", length = 15)
private long mobileNumber1;

@Column(name="MobileNumber2", length = 15)
private long mobileNumber2;

@Column(name="DOB", length = 15)
private Date dob;

@OneToOne   
private UserEntity userEntity;
```

// getter and setters here

Comment: I found the solution myself . let me update .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself . let me update . just mention annotation OneToOne in parents table(here is Users). and child table that is UserDetails's Id would be stored in parent table.   `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserDetailsId", nullable = false)
private UserDetailsEntity userDetailsEntity;`
and my requirement get completed and nothing to do with UserDetailsEntity.